# The right place to install GRUB bootloader and the best configuration to install Ubuntu (and something else)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I know the question could be a bit repeated, but I've seen so many tutorials and opinions so I prefer to post about my facts (or problem, depending the point of view):

I've successfully booted up Ubuntu 16.04.1 from my USB in my UEFI laptop, even with SecureBoot enabled, only disabling FastBoot from Windows 10. But I still have a few questions about installation:

- My computer has four partitions (EFI/Bootloader partition, Recovery Partition, OS Partition (where Windows 10 is), DATA Partition (only generic data, nothing else). Do I need to install Ubuntu from the "Something Else" option?
- And my biggest doubt: Do I need to install GRUB bootloader at the same Windows Boot Partition (EFI Partition), or do I need to create a second "Boot" partition for the GRUB bootloader? 
  Some tutorials give the first option, others give the second, that's why I have the doubt.

Also some issues I had at my Ubuntu Live Session were:

- Touchpad from my laptop doesn't work: Probably some issue from Asus drivers (Wi-Fi worked out of the box, and at first impression graphics and sound were working fine). The touchpad was detected at Terminal, but it wasn't working.
- CPU status LEDs (Battery, Disk Activity, Airplane Mode) working incorrectly: I don't know if this one can be an issue for not disabling SecureBoot, but LED status indicators were not working correctly. The "Airplane Mode" LED was turned on, while no "Airplane Mode" was enabled". The "Disk Activity" LED was not even turned on.
- Screen Brightness at maximum capacity:  I remember at older Ubuntu installations (on my old computer) similar problems, but I'm not pretty sure why it was caused.

My computer: Asus X556U, 1 TB HDD, 8 GB RAM, Intel Core i7 6200U, two graphic cards (Intel integrated and Nvidia GeForce 940M)

I have been using Ubuntu for a while at VM, but I just don't want to jump to a physical install because my last time I had some issues with my old computer (I messed up Ubuntu and Windows), so I want your guide and opinions. All help will be welcomed.

Comment: This is a Q&A website, not a forum. It works best if you ask one question. If you need extensive troubleshooting there are other help resources available, like Ubuntu Forums. Also googling brand/model + Ubuntu gives results and discussions from other users. Also ignore the "answer" below which is too generic and almost only applicable in Legacy/CSM mode.

Comment: With Windows 8+ you need also consider disabling *fast startup* before anything else, then use Windows tools to shrink one or more partitions because you want to have **unallocated** space (not just free space inside partitions), shutdown and turn it on again, let *chkdsk* (Windows tool for error correcting drives) do its job if called, basically assure your Windows ios booting fine with the new settings and partition size. Then you can boot Ubuntu (in UEFI mode) and install. "Alongside..." should now work.

Comment: Additional info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI. Use an external mouse to install if you must. Then, if the problem with the touchpad persists I suggest you open a new question focused on that and only that.

Comment: Whether UEFI or BIOS you only install grub to a drive like sda, never to a partition. With UEFI grub will add another folder in the ESP - efi system partition with it boot files. While UEFI spec may say multiple ESP are allowed we have not seem systems that work with more than one. So only one ESP  fat32 with boot flag if using gparted/parted or code ef00 if using gdisk to create partitions. this was a 555, not sure if your 556 is similar or not: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327570

Answer (score -2):

**Installation**

- If you have Windows installed on your system, and you're trying to install Ubuntu, firstly, make sure you have enough **unallocated space** on your HDD.
- If you don't, try shredding the available partitions using Windows settings.Then, plug your bootable ubuntu CD/flash drive.

  Most probably Ubuntu will detect the free space and the installation of Windows on your machine. It will display an option of "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10" in the installation menu. Then, you wouldn't have to select the **Something Else** option. You can go ahead and install Ubuntu without a thought.

  Through **Something Else** option, one can manually select the free space part of HDD where you want to install Ubuntu. This option may/may not recognise pre-existing Windows installation.

  The **GRUB/bootloader** will take care of itself after a successful Ubuntu installation. Most probably, you will be greeted with a GRUB menu on reboot, where you can select Ubuntu/Windows to boot into.

**Touchpad**

- There is probably some problem with the driver of your touchpad.
- To resolve this issue, after the installtion of Ubuntu, use shortcuts/external mouse to reach the Setting->Software&Updates->Additional Driver and look for an alternate driver for your touchpad.